# Matching an argument with a function in Jasmine

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I want to perform a custom assertion about the argument passed to a spied-on function call. Can I supply a callback to be used within the expectation against an argument?

```
expect(my.method).toHaveBeenCalledWith(jasmine.argumentMatching(myCustomCallback), jasmine.any({}));
```

... Where `jasmine.argumentMatching(myCustomCallback)` is pseudo code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Jasmine spy has a property `.calls`, which provides information about the number of calls, arguments for particular calls, etc. Take a look at this docs section - [Other tracking properties](http://jasmine.github.io/2.3/introduction.html#section-Other_tracking_properties). It depends on your requirements which one would you use, and in documentation it is described very well, but in general:

- `.calls.argsFor(n)` - returns array of arguments for n-th call
- `.calls.allArgs()` - returns array of arrays of arguments for all calls
- `.calls.mostRecent()`, `.calls.first()` - return an object in form:

  ```
   { object: my, args: ['foo', 42], returnValue: undefined }
  ```
- `.calls.all()` - returns array of objects (like one above)

In general it will look like:

```
spyOn(my, 'method');

my.method('foo', 42);

expect(my.method.calls.argsFor(0)).toEqual(['foo', 42]);
```